# Why does grep seem to die after 30 minutes?

Tags: macos, grep

I'm trying to grep my entire iMac using this command:

```
grep -rnwl / -e "Birthdaysx" 1>birthdaysx.txt 2>birthdaysxerrors.txt
```

I can see it is very busy in Activity Manager for a while, then after 30 minutes CPU usage drops to zero, although it still appears in the list, and never returns to the prompt.  (`birthdaysxerrors.txt` lists some Permission denied, recursive directory loop etc errors as expected.)

What can I do to keep it running?

Comment: Take `dtruss` and find out what is going on.

Comment: just an observation: `-n` option won't work with `-l` option specified..

Comment: @zerkms thanks, I tried `sudo dtruss -n grep` but just got `PID/THRD SYSCALL(args) = return` and no other output.  Are there other options I should try?